# How to collect information from nav tab and submit as single form

Tags: django, forms, nav

I am using NAV to collect information from user, instead of one single view, so thought to divide up into nav tab and at the end get all the data and submit.

I'm using Django, with Model with define fields, View is get valid POST.

Here is the HTML looks like:

```
<div align="center" class="container">
<form id="collectINFO" role=form method="POST" class="nav nav-pills post-form" action="{% url 'collectINFO' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul align="center" class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-rose">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#pill1" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pill2" data-toggle="tab">TAB2</a></li>

</ul>
    <div class="tab-content tab-space">
        <div align="center"class="tab-pane active" id="pill1">
          <br><br>
          <input name="input1" id="input1" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="20" required />
           <input name="input2" id="input2" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="2" required />
      </div> <!-- end of pill-1 -->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="pill2">
          <div class="row"><div class="col">
           <input id="data1" class="form-control" rows="1" type="text" name="hostname" maxlength="20" required></input>
            </div></div> <!-- end of pill-2 -->
</div>
<div align="center" class="container">
<div id="submit" class="row">
<div class=" col">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SAVE</button>
</form></div>
```

When I hit `SAVE` nothing happens no log also in the VIEW I have added

`print(form.error)` and `print(form)`
here is the VIEW looks like

```
def CollectINFO(request, *args, **kwargs):
    template_name = 'CollectINFO.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CollectINFO_Form(request.POST or None)
        print(form.is_valid())
        print(form.error)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'SUCCESSFULLY!!!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
    else:
        form = CollectINFO_Form()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form })
```

Please advise, how to submit the information. Not able to see the data is being `POST` which is not being validating.. not sure why.. thanks

After some debug, noticed the nav is sending "GET" not `POST`
*** how to collect data from the all the finds and send data as POST when submitting

Comment: change print(form.error) to print(form.errors) to see what is going on. you may forget to fill a required field. that is why you are not seeing the errors. Also, you should render the error manually.  use {{form.errors}} and {{ form.non_field_errors }}  please check this out https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

Answer (score 0):

```
In your model(say List) if you have name , email and description and if the input1 , 
input2 and input3 means those three fields, you need to save them individually in 
Views like:
input1 = form.input1
input2 = form.input2
input3 = form.input3
list = List.objects.create()
list.name = input1
list.email = input2
list.description = input3
list.save()


///////
and even check your url its supposed to have the correct  view lined with the name of 
the url so that it links up correct to the template form action.
```